# Scheme Recursion Through Arguments

Tags: recursion, scheme

I'm brand new to Scheme, and this is a homework question, so please no outright answers.

Here is my question:

> Write a recursive procedure (any? arg1 arg2 ...), where the argi's are
>   boolean values. any? returns #t if any of its arguments is #t, and #f
>   otherwise.

These are the constraints:

> You may not use the built-in procedures map, apply, list->vector, or
>   vector->list in any procedure. Likewise, do not use a let expression
>   or an internal define expression in any procedure, unless the problem
>   says otherwise.

Here is the code I have:::

```
(define any?
  (lambda args
    (if (null? args)
        #f
        (if (equal? #t (car args))
            #t
            (any? (cdr args))))))
```

My problem seems to be that I am hitting an infinite loop on the last line (any? (cdr args)). I am not sure why that is happening. My professor said a hint was to write any? as an interface procedure, and write a helper that handles the list. I am not sure how that would help.

Any advice would be appreciated!

EDIT: I have added new code. I am still getting an infinite loop.

```
(define any?
  (lambda args
    (any-helper args)))

(define any-helper
  (lambda (list)
    (if (null? list)
        #f
        (if (equal? #t (car list))
            #t
            (any? (cdr list))))))
```

I thought by writing lambda args in my main function, I would be passing a list to my helper function. I'm not sure if that is actually happening. I am not sure how to ensure that I don't recurse over '() infinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the steps taken by the function application `(any? #f)`. This leads to a recursive call to `(any? '())`. Next, it checks to see if the argument list in this call, `'(())`, is `null?` (which it isn't, since it is a list containing `'()`). `(equal #t '(())` is also false, so it keeps recursing since you're calling it with the same number of arguments instead of reducing the size of the input in each recursive call.

<sub>Hey, this is my 100th answer!</sub>

Comment: Thank you! I am not sure how to reduce the size of the list each time besides using cdr. I'm guessing I should not be checking null on each pass.

Comment: @AbigailB I changed "reduce the size of the argument list" to "reduce the size of the input" because reducing the size of the list of arguments isn't possible given the restrictions on the assignment. This is why your professor suggested the creation of a helper function.

Comment: I added more code. I am still not sure what is wrong.

Comment: @AbigailB You're calling `any?` from `any-helper` instead of doing direct recursion with `any-helper`, so `any?` is being called recursively with a single element in its argument list each time.

Comment: Woooooow, do I feel dumb for overlooking that! Thank you for your help :) I checked your solution!

Answer (score 1):

When you have a symbol argument or a dotted list as prototype the last argument, in your case `args`, contains the rest of the given operands.

Imagine you evaluate `(any? #f 5 6)` then `args` would be `(#f 5 6)`. Since first argument is `#f` you then call `(any? '(5 6))` instead of `(any? 5 6)`.

Usually you would make a named `let` or a local procedure to handle a one argument list so that your code actually would work, but since you are not allowed to you need to use `apply` to do this instead.

`(apply any? '(#f 5 6))` is the same as `(any? #f 5 6)`. You can think of `apply` as the opposite as dotted list/symbol prototype in a procedure definition.

PS: Your update using `any-helper` would work perfectly if you recurse with `any-helper` instead of `any?`.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't use apply either, unfortunately. :)